# Logstash Gelf - Multiple sources

Tags: logstash, filebeat, gelf

I am trying to use gelf input plugin for some ESB logs with GELF Layout (just started ELK Stack for logging). I am successful in getting the logs through a configured port. As there are around 100 apps (will keep adding) and some are WebServices which keeps spitting logs is it ok to have all logs through a single port as would that create any performance problem or missing some logs? Like LS - File beat has that backpressure-sensitive protocol, is there something like this in gelf Input plugin?

```
input {  
    gelf{
        host => "testelkstacksrvr1"
        port => 9090
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use GELF over TCP. NXLog can also do this and flow-control will prevent logs getting dropped.